# Query returning same customer

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have two records for the same customer but with different customerLastUpdated dates, there is a way to return only the most recent one?

```
var response = await this.client.SearchAsync<ElasticCustomer>(searchDescriptor => searchDescriptor
    .AllTypes()
    .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b
            .Should(
                sh => sh.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.CustomerName).Query(query)),
                sh => sh.Wildcard(w => w.Field(f => f.MobileNumber.Suffix("keyword")).Value($"*{query}*")))));
```

Comment: You can sort the result by descending date and take the first record

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, the problem is the results will be displayed in a grid so I really need to remove the duplicates. I'm trying to use Aggregations however I couldn't make it work and not sure if it's the correct way